# How to extract people who have only performed an activity once from a table

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Name   Activity
John   ViewReport
John   UploadData
John   ViewDashboard
Ted    ViewReport
Ted    DownloadData
Amanda ViewReport
Amanda ViewDashboard
Lee    ViewDashboard
Kathy  ViewDataset
```

I want to filter this table so that it only shows people have done a "view" activity. In this case, John and Ted are excluded because although they do have "view" activities, they also have other activities.

```
Name   Activity
Amanda ViewReport
Amanda ViewDashboard
Lee    ViewDashboard
Kathy  ViewDataset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach could be

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  filter(all(str_detect(Activity, "View"))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Name   Activity     
  <chr>  <chr>        
1 Amanda ViewReport   
2 Amanda ViewDashboard
3 Lee    ViewDashboard
4 Kathy  ViewDataset
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution with `ave`.

```
i <- as.logical(with(df1, ave(Activity, Name, FUN = \(x){
  length(x) == length(grep("view", x, ignore.case = TRUE))
})))
df1[i, ]
#    Name      Activity
#6 Amanda    ViewReport
#7 Amanda ViewDashboard
#8    Lee ViewDashboard
#9  Kathy   ViewDataset
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Name   Activity
John   ViewReport
John   UploadData
John   ViewDashboard
Ted    ViewReport
Ted    DownloadData
Amanda ViewReport
Amanda ViewDashboard
Lee    ViewDashboard
Kathy  ViewDataset
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  inner_join((data %>%
              mutate(view = str_detect(Activity, "View"), 
                     no_view = str_detect(Activity, "View", negate = T)) %>%
              group_by(Name) %>%
              summarise(view_flg = max(view),
                        no_view_flg = max(no_view)) %>%
              filter(view == 1 & no_view_flg == 1) %>%
              ungroup()), by = "Name")
```

The way I am interpreting your question is that you have to make sure each person of interest has "View" somewhere in their activity and only "View". If that is the case then you also may need to test to make sure they have nothing else (hence the `no_view = str_detect(Activity, "View", negate = T)`).